# Filtering duplicate array value before inserting array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array values like below

```
var name = ["java","php","python"] //get from user

var res = [{"name":"mysql"}, {"name":"golang"}, {"name":"svelte"}] //response from json
```

I want to check the array value I get above with data existing I get using response JSON first, then insert the array `name`.

If all the data array `name` has the same value with one data in `res` as the data response, it will show `alert` javascript. If all data array `name` doesn't have any value with `res` from response JSON, it will insert all the array `name`.

Right now, I just success created an insert array using `$.each`.

I want to ask about how I make filtering value to check data we get from input user with response JSON before I insert an array

Here's the code I used to insert an array

```
  var now = 0;
  var totalName = name.length;
  $.each(name, function (x,y) {
    $.ajax({
      url:"<?= base_url();?>controller/function",
      type:"POST",
      dataType:"json",
      data:{"name":y},
      success: function(response){
        now++;
        if (now == totalName)
        {
            setTimeout(() => {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Success',
                    timer: 1500,
                    showConfirmButton: false
                }).then((res) => {
                    location.reload();
                });
            }, 500);
            
          }
        }
     })
   })
```

Comment: "I want to ask about how I make filtering value to check data we get from input user with response json before I insert array" - what do you want to check then?

Comment: I want to check data I get with data existing using json, then insert it using json too

Comment: So you want to insert into `res` from `name` all values that are not already in `res`?

Comment: Hi @Ivan86, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array.prorotype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

Contains duplicates *mysql* and *golang*:

```js
let name = ["java","php","python","mysql","golang"]; //get from user
var res = [{"name":"mysql"}, {"name":"golang"}, {"name":"svelte"}]; //response from json

let duplicates = [];

name.forEach(function(item) {
  if(res.some(elem => elem.name === item))
    duplicates.push(item);
});

if(duplicates.length > 0) {
  alert("The user array contains duplicates:\n " + duplicates);
} else {
  name.forEach(function(item) {
    res.push({"name": item});
  });
}

console.log(res);
```

No duplicates:

```js
let name = ["java","php","python"]; //get from user
var res = [{"name":"mysql"}, {"name":"golang"}, {"name":"svelte"}]; //response from json

let duplicates = [];

name.forEach(function(item) {
  if(res.some(elem => elem.name === item))
    duplicates.push(item);
});

if(duplicates.length > 0) {
  alert("The user array contains duplicates:\n " + duplicates);
} else {
  name.forEach(function(item) {
    res.push({"name": item});
  });
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi @Ivan86, I think I give you wrong statement. What I want is to check all `name` with `res`, if all data in `name` is not exist in `res`, it will push, but if 1 data in `name` is exist in `res`, it will show an alert, and all the data is not push into `name`

Comment: @IkramShabri what if *some* but not all of the elements in name are in res? Still show alert?

Comment: @IkramShabri In that case what happens after it shows the alert, do the rest of the elements that are not in res still get pushed?

Comment: Hi @Ivan86, if it shows alert, all data is not push